# Getting parameters in integration testing MSTesting C#

Tags: c#, testing, integration-testing, mstest

I need to get a lot of parameters to dynamically build a test method. My limits is it has to be in MSTest and C#.

What I'm thinking is something of the likes of:

```
[TestMethod]
public void test1 (int x, int y, string url, double l)
{
     // Use parameters here
}
```

I know this is not possible, I get that. But that is ultimately what I need to get.

Can anyone share some insight on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [MSTest V2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2017/02/25/mstest-v2-now-and-ahead/) you can do this using the **DataRowAttribute**. For example:

```
[TestMethod]
[DataRow(1, 2, "http://kuku.com", 3.4)]
[DataRow(4, 5, "http://foo.com", 6.7)]
public void test1 (int x, int y, string url, double l)
{
     // Use parameters here
}
```

This will cause the test to run twice, once for each set of values specified by the corresponding DataRowAttribute.